# ActiveRecord query GROUP and COUNT zero values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an attendance table that I'm trying to query in order to create a dataset that I can graph with. My table stores attendance information like so:

```
date       | student_id | present | session |
-----------|------------|---------|---------|
2012-09-01 | 1          | 1       | AM      |
2012-09-01 | 1          | 1       | PM      |
2012-09-01 | 2          | 0       | AM      |
2012-09-01 | 2          | 1       | PM      |
2012-09-02 | 1          | 0       | AM      |
2012-09-02 | 1          | 0       | PM      |
2012-09-02 | 2          | 0       | AM      |
2012-09-02 | 2          | 0       | PM      |
```

I'm trying to end up with a dataset that has each unique date, along with the number of present marks (divided by two, eventually, for a kinda accurate representation of attendance for each day).

```
2012-09-01 | 3 (1.5)
2012-09-02 | 0 (0)
```

This is so far the closest I've got

```
AttendanceMark.group(:date).count(:conditions => "present = 1")
```

but this resulting hash doesn't include the dates where there are no present marks at all. How  would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 0 and 1 for present and absent respectively, you can construct a query like this

```
# For MySQL
AttendanceMark.group(:date).sum('CASE present WHEN TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END')

# For SQLite
AttendanceMark.group(:date).sum('CASE WHEN present = "t" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END')
```

This shall return

```
{ "2012-09-01" => 3, "2012-09-02" => 0 }
```

You can later divide all the sums by two.

Comment: it's a tinyint(1) column in mysql and rails recognises this as a boolean and therefore it's not working :(.

Comment: Updated my answer. We'll have to use Mysql case statement. Note that this is database dependent.